# How to run queries properly after restoring a db in Sql Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following query runs line 1 then fails on line 2 because it cannot find the db "because it does not exist". In SSMS 2012, i can get this to work by refreshing the database manually but i need to do it via a query. is there some way to refresh or whatever is necessary to make the db appear to exist?

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup_2014_01_13_000002_3436250.bak' 

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting the context to `[MyDb]`, before executing line 2. Try this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup_2014_01_13_000002_3436250.bak'
GO
USE [MyDb] 
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable;
GO
```